# Is there a list of old community choice games/options in the winter sale on steam?

Tags: steam

I would like to know if there is a list of the games previously up for Community Choice in the Winter Sale on steam, including those that didn't win. It would be a good, for example, to have a reminder of ones that I voted for that weren't made community choice, as I might still like to buy them.

Comment: The /r/Games subreddit keeps a [list of sale items](http://www.reddit.com/r/Games/search?q=Steam+Winter+Sale+-+Day&sort=new&restrict_sr=on). I'm not sure how complete it is though

Comment: I've had a look. It only seems to have the Community Choice winner, and only the current one at the time of posting, not the other 2 from that day.

Comment: Ah yes it seems like that is the one piece of information it is missing, quite right.